# How can i make my AngularJS website crawled on google?

Tags: angularjs

I want to remove # from my angularjs app, I am developing an website, I think it may help to make SEO friendly website, May be i am wrong, Please help
Thanks

Comment: http://prerender.io or roll server side rendering your own.

Comment: its open source - https://github.com/prerender/prerender - you can run in your own server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Joe Lloyd for the way to remove the # from your url but it won't help you to make your angularjs website crawlable.
Check out the following steps :

1. Configure the html5mode

   config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
2. Add `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` to your pages so the google bot knows to add the ?_escaped_fragment_= at the end of your request.
3. Handle the `?_escaped_fragment_=`on the server side and serve a static snapshot of the requested html page (phantomjs  can make the job) so the bot will index the rendered version of the html page.
4. Populate your sitemap.xml and send it to google using www.google.com/webmasters/

Have fun !

Comment: I am using XAMPP as local server, my website path is http://localhost/mysite
after the First step when i open http://localhost/mysite, it redirect me to http://localhost
I didn't do anything server side, i am using PHP.
Are there some .htaccess stuff, that i have to do ?
Thanks

Comment: Try to add <base href="/mysite/"> to your index page

Comment: thanks, how can i handle ?_escaped_fragment_= with htaccess

Answer (score 1):

## Config

To remove the # in your url you need to add this to your main module. You put the app into html5 mode.

```
//This config is used to remove the # in the html
app.config(["$locationProvider", function($locationProvider) {
   $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
   });
}]);
```

## Server Side (NodeJS)

This will have a server side effect when you hit refresh you need to add an extra route that is able to find the new url. this will work in your express js `app.js` file. Where the public folder contains your angular app and you have your `index.html` file in there

```
// ### CATCH REFRESH TO INDEX ###
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
    res.sendFile('public/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

Comment: @christophe.chapron I'm not sure to be honest, my answer just removes the hash in the url and lets the nodejs server know how to handle the new paths.

Comment: yes i agree, but it won't help at all for SEO :)
@Punit : read http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html + google documentation concerning ajax website

Comment: I am using PHP in server side, can you help with that ? OR is there any possibility by HTACCESS file

Comment: @christophe.chapron : you are right, search engines read this ?_escaped_fragment_=, can we do server side routing by htaccess ?

Comment: yes you can do it with an htaccess (at least for simple cases)