# AngularJS website pre-render with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, .htaccess

I am trying 
AngularJS website pre-render with PHP for SEO.
I have already removed hash bang as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798647/how-can-i-make-my-angularjs-website-crawled-on-google)

I want to know some solution that is free, i heard about http://prerender.io/
but its not free. Thanks for help

Comment: If you want SEO for google. Google can crawl any website just like they do. Any  JavaScript framework can work with Google

Comment: @haseeb : As per my knowledge google and bing replaces #! with "?_escaped_fragment_=" in AngularJS, So we have to handle this by some way. Without handling this google is not crawling any website on AJAX.

Comment: You can look at Google cached website of any JavaScript based website. I don't know what about Bing

Comment: @haseeb Yes i have seen that, Its now crawling :(

Comment: If prerender.io can do it. Google can also

Comment: @haseeb : hahaha.. i appreciate your faith on google, anyways thanks :)

Comment: Except everything haseeb wrote here is wrong, he clearly do not understand how pre-rendering works.... prerender.io is free if you host it yourself.